# LaTeX3 keyval forwarding

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, arguments, l3keys

Say I want to write a command `igtest`, which works identically as `\includegraphics` from `graphicx`, except that if the page number is given, e.g. `\igtest[page=5]{someimg}`, then the page number is overwritten by 1, i.e. it should work as `\includegraphics[page=1]{someimg}`. (It's a MWE, so don't ask why I want to do this...)

My attempt is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { ig_keys } {
    page.tl_set:N   = \l_ig_page_tl
}
\tl_new:N \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\igtest}{O{} m}
 {
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ig_keys }{ #1 }\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NTF{\l_ig_page_tl}{
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2} 
    }{
        \includegraphics[\tl_use:N\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl,page=1]{#2}
    }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\igtest[width=\textwidth,page=2]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

The roadmap is clear: capture the page key individually, store other keys as unknown keys in a token list `\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl`, then forward it to `\includegraphics`.

The code doesn't work. Obviously, I do not use `\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl` correctly.

How to fix that? Or is it fixable (since `\includegraphics` is not written with LaTeX3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\use:x`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { ig_keys } {
    page.tl_set:N   = \l_ig_page_tl
}
\tl_new:N \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\igtest}{O{} m}
 {
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ig_keys }{ #1 }\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NTF{\l_ig_page_tl}{
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2} 
    }{
        \use:x{
            \exp_not:N\includegraphics[\exp_not:V \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl,page=1]{\exp_not:n{#2}}
        }
    }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\igtest[width=\textwidth,page=2]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

This builds up some code to be executed (as the x-expansion of whatever there are in the argument), then execute it. (to print out what code is actually executed just change `\use:x` to `\tl_show:x` or something similar.)

Comment: You could curry the mandatory argument to `\includegraphics` instead of using `\exp_not:n` on it: `\use:x { \exp_not:N \includegraphics [ \exp_not:V \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl }, page=1] {#2}`. Or you could use `\exp_last_unbraced:NNV \includegraphics [ \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl, page=1]{#2}` (I didn't check whether that variant of `\exp_last_unbraced:N...` exists).

Comment: The code in this answer has the potential issue to affect not only this call, but all future calls of `\igtest` as the `\l_ig_page_tl` is never reset.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an internal copy of `\includegraphics`, so you can define variants thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { ig_keys }
  {
    page.tl_set:N = \l_ig_page_tl,
  }
\tl_new:N \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ig_ig:nnn { \includegraphics[#1,#2]{#3} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ig_ig:nnn { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\igtest}{O{} m}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ig_keys }{ #1 } \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_ig_page_tl
      {
        \__ig_ig:nnn { #1 } { } { #2 } 
      }
      {
        \__ig_ig:Vnn \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl { page=1 } { #2 }
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\igtest[width=3cm,angle=30,page=2]{example-image-a}

\igtest[width=3cm,angle=30]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` unless you first clear the possible value of `\l_ig_page_tl`.

[image]

Even more compact:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { ig_keys }
  {
    page.tl_set:N = \l_ig_page_tl,
  }
\tl_new:N \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ig_ig:nnn { \includegraphics[#1,#2]{#3} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ig_ig:nnn { Ve }

\NewDocumentCommand{\igtest}{O{} m}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ig_keys }{ #1 } \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl
    \__ig_ig:Ven \l__ig_unknown_keys_tl { \tl_if_empty:NF \l_ig_page_tl { page=1 } } { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: You are right! I considered using `\cs_generate_variant`, but obviously I'm not familiar with these expansion things :-P

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is expansion related (`\includegraphics` doesn't "see" the keys as they were passed in, but only `\tl_use:N\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl,page=1`, so tries to parse `\tl_use:N\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl` as a single key, which fails), and the [answer by user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683214/117050) shows how to fix that (by expanding `\l__ig_unknown_keys_tl` to its value before `\includegraphics` expands).

The following uses `expkv-cs` instead to implement that filter behaviour, this way no expansion tricks are necessary at all. Note however that this mechanism only works for up to 8 keys you want to filter this way (else you'd need another macro of `expkv-cs` that might require expansion tricks again...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \igtest {O{} m} { \__ig_test_filter_page:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ekvcSplit \__ig_test_filter_page:nn
  {
    page=, % #1 will be the value of the page key, and empty if it was unused
    ...    % #2 will be all the unknown keys
  }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \includegraphics [#2] }
      { \includegraphics [#2, page=1] }
    % the mandatory argument to \includegraphics will be curried
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, page=1]{example-image-duck}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, page=5]{example-image-duck}

\igtest[width=5cm, page=5]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Minor issue: `\__ig_test_filter_page:nn` will not be defined `\protected` though it should be since it expands to the unexpandable `\includegraphics` macro.